# Downgrade kernel by deleting new one from /boot?

Tags: boot, kernel, downgrade

I manually installed kernel 5.10.3, but now want to downgrade since I need NVIDIA's CUDA. If I delete the newer ones, will it boot from older ones - or not boot at all? (I have no physical access to this machine, only from terminal)

Ubuntu 18.04.5. I installed new kernel by:

```
cd /tmp/
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.3/amd64/linux-headers-5.10.3-051003-generic_5.10.3-051003.202012261630_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.3/amd64/linux-headers-5.10.3-051003_5.10.3-051003.202012261630_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.3/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.10.3-051003-generic_5.10.3-051003.202012261630_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.3/amd64/linux-modules-5.10.3-051003-generic_5.10.3-051003.202012261630_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot
```

In /boot I have now:

```
ls -1

config-5.10.3-051003-generic
config-5.4.58-050458-generic
grub
initrd.img-5.10.3-051003-generic
initrd.img-5.4.58-050458-generic
memtest86+.bin
memtest86+.elf
memtest86+_multiboot.bin
System.map-5.10.3-051003-generic
System.map-5.4.58-050458-generic
vmlinuz-5.10.3-051003-generic
vmlinuz-5.4.58-050458-generic
```

Comment: And how did you install the 5.10.3?

Comment: I just edited the original post to answer you questions. Thank you

Comment: you have to choose kernel 5.4.58 in grub under advanced options. then you can remove kernel 5.10.3.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to remove your new kernel without problem (apt remove command). But if you don't use apt to install your kernel, you have to do `sudo update-grub` at the end of removal to detect again the available kernels. This will update your grub boot menu.

Comment: I did, but it still boots the newer one

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete any files manually. That will break your system.

To uninstall the 5.10 kernel you need to uninstall the deb packages.

Run

```
sudo apt remove linux-headers-5.10.3-051003-generic linux-headers-5.10.3-051003 linux-modules-5.10.3-051003-generic linux-image-unsigned-5.10.3-051003-generic
```

Comment: I got warning like below. Can I proceed?
You are running a kernel (version 5.10.3-051003-generic) and attempting to remove the same version. This can make the system unbootable as it will remove
 /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.3-051003-generic and all modules under the directory
 /lib/modules/5.10.3-051003-generic. This can only be fixed with a copy of the kernel image and the corresponding modules.
 It is highly recommended to abort the kernel removal unless you are prepared to fix the system after removal. Abort kernel removal?

Comment: It is better to reboot first and select another kernel in grub menu. But if you are sure that the system will boot with the 5.4 kernel, you can proceed.

Comment: Agree with @Pilot6, you can proceed anyway, but you have to restart right after.

Comment: Thank you, it did worked